# Singularity being essential and removable in the same time (contradiction)

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://psm73.files.wordpress.com/2009/03/conway.pdf) and on page 103 he proved the following theorem:

[image]

I'm trying to classify the singularity of $z\sin \frac{1}{z}$. Using this theorem we have $\lim_{z\to 0}z^2\sin\frac{1}{z}=0$, since $(z^2\to 0)$ and $\sin\frac{1}{z}$ is bounded. Therefore this singularity is removable.

The problem is using Laurent series, we have this singularity is an essential one:

$$f(z)=z\sin \frac{1}{z}=1-\frac{1}{3!z^2}+\frac{1}{5!z^4}-\frac{1}{7!z^6}+\ldots$$

So what's my mistake?

Comment: $\sin \frac{1}{z}$ is not bounded. Try approaching $0$ through purely imaginary values.

Comment: @DanielFischer I can't see it. Using the definition of the sine, we have $\sin\frac{1}{z}\approxeq \frac{1}{z}$, then $\sin\frac{1}{i^k}=\frac{1}{i^k}$. Therefore, we have $\sin\frac{1}{z}\approxeq-i,-1,i,1\ldots$ for $k=1,2,3,4,\ldots$. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: No, you have $\sin \frac{1}{z} \approx \frac{1}{z}$ for **large** $\lvert z\rvert$. Use $\sin z = \frac{1}{2i}\bigl(e^{iz} - e^{-iz}\bigr)$. Then you see that for $0 < t \ll 1$ you have $\sin \frac{1}{it} \approx \frac{1}{2i} e^{1/t}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I understand now. Thank you very much.